# Wicket on self written java based server

Tags: java, webserver, wicket

Hey yall, I have a wicket- and also a server-related question:

We built a little server with java (yeah, I know, why re-invent the wheel ... I got that a lot when I asked the question on the wicket-mailing-list) .... so let's just say, it is desperately needed b/c ... ehm ... I still can't think of a good reason, but there's not a lot I can do about it ... so I finally got this little server to run servlets ... as far as I know, to run wicket you need a server that can run servlets ... (as for my lack of english let's just say: it is supposed to be a servlet container like tomcat) ... now that I do have this very beautiful server, does anybody have an idea what I have to do, so that my wicket-apps run on it? how do I tell my server that it is supposed to run a wicket-app?

Hope I explained it well ... 
thnx in advance :)

... dg

---

ok, a little source ... I did this following a tutorial:

HttpServer where the "magic" happens:

```
 while (!shutdown) {
  // ... all the stuff before

    //check if this is a request for a servlet or a static resource
    //a request for a servlet begins with "/servlet/"
    if (request.getUri().startsWith("/servlet/")) {
        System.out.println( "SERVLET-REQUEST\n\n" );
      ServletProcessor2 processor = new ServletProcessor2();
      processor.process(request, response);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println( "STATICRESOURCE-REQUEST" );
      StaticResourceProcessor processor = new StaticResourceProcessor();
      processor.process(request, response);
    }
 // ... all the stuff after
}
```

Now the ServletProcessor:

```
public class ServletProcessor2 {

public void process(Request request, Response response) {

 String uri = request.getUri();
 String servletName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
 System.out.println( "SERVLETNAME ... " + servletName );
 URLClassLoader loader = null;

try {
   // create a URLClassLoader
   URL[] urls = new URL[1];
   URLStreamHandler streamHandler = null;
   File classPath = new File(Constants.WEB_ROOT);
   // the forming of repository is taken from the createClassLoader method in
   // org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory
   String repository = (new URL("file", null, classPath.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator)).toString() ;
   System.out.println( "REPOSITORY ... " + repository );
   // the code for forming the URL is taken from the addRepository method in
   // org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader class.
   urls[0] = new URL(null, repository, streamHandler);
   loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.toString() );
 }
 Class myClass = null;
 try {
   myClass = loader.loadClass(servletName);
 }
 catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println("FEHLER: " + e.toString() + " ... CAUSE: " + e.getCause() );
   e.printStackTrace();
 }

 Servlet servlet = null;
 RequestFacade requestFacade = new RequestFacade(request);
 ResponseFacade responseFacade = new ResponseFacade(response);
 try {
     servlet = (Servlet) myClass.newInstance();
     servlet.service((ServletRequest) requestFacade, (ServletResponse) responseFacade);
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println( "Fehler: " + e.toString() + " ... CAUSE: " + e.getCause() );
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch (Throwable e) {
   System.out.println(e.toString());
 }

}
}
```

Comment: How can we answer something about your server? How do you run a servlet on your server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simple answer is that you will need to implement the [Servlet API](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/). The wicket documentation  doesn't seem to say what the exact required version but I'm sure it'll be at least 2.4. Not a job I'd recommend you do, it's a difficult thing to do correctly and your just opening your self to a world of pain.

If you need to embed a server then might I recommend you start with [jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) and customise it to meet what ever requirements you have. Jetty has a very permissive license so you don't have to worry about using in a commercial product and can scale pretty much with the best of them.

Comment: thank you gid, that's somehow the answer I was expecting ... at least the "it is not easy, better dun do it ..."-part ... sad but true ... Thank you!

Comment: Just looking at your ServletRequest processor...there is a bit more to running a servlet than just creating it and calling service(). There a whole servlet life cycle to implement and that's just for starters

Comment: good to know that I am not underestimating this whole server thing for nothing ... just need to explain that to my boss *g*